# Symfony2 - Doctrine2 - MySql: Composite FK and PK

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am using Symfony2, Doctrine2 and MySql. I have two tables: Review and Topic. Review has a composite PK (idReview and idHotel). Topic has only one PK (idTopic). I want to create a many-to-many relation between these two tables. The join table resulting (e.g Review_Topic) must have a composite PK (idReview, idHotel, idTopic) made of the three FK. When I update the schema, MySql gives me the error 1005, can't create table, errno 150 because of the FK (idReview, idHotel).Following the Yaml configuration of Review and Topic including the many-to-many relation:

```
Review:
...
    manyToMany:
        topics:
            targetEntity: Topic
            inversedBy: reviews
            joinTable:
                name: reviews_topics
                joinColumns:
                    idReview:
                        referencedColumnName: idReview
                    idHotel:
                        referencedColumnName: idHotel
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    topic_id:
                        referencedColumnName: idTopic
                fields:
                    score:
                        type: integer

Topic:
...
    manyToMany:
        reviews:
            targetEntity: Review
            mappedBy: topics
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to change your Review entity like this

```
Review:
...

manyToMany:
    topics:          
      targetEntity: Topic
      joinTable:
        name: reviews_topics
        joinColumns:
          review_id:
            referencedColumnName: idReview
        inverseJoinColumns:
          topic_id:
            referencedColumnName: idTopic               
        inversedBy: reviews
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur response. But the Review table has a composite PK (idReview and idHotel). U didn't specify the PK idHotel in the many-to-many relation. The idReview PK value is not unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charme. The error was because I've forgotten the last two lines.